# pyramid transaction.manager doesn't update object

Tags: python-3.x, transactions, sqlalchemy, pyramid

How can I update a row in DB using transaction.manager in Pyramid? Here is what I have:

DBSession:

```
DBSession = scoped_session(sessionmaker(extension=ZopeTransactionExtension()))
```

View:

```
def create_update(request, post):
  title = request.POST.get('title', None)
  content = request.POST.get('content', None)

  post.title = title
  post.content = content

  with transaction.manager:
    if post.id is None:
        DBSession.add(post)
    transaction.commit()
```

This is how I get an existing post from DB:

```
def by_slug(slug):
  return DBSession.query(BlogPost).filter(BlogPost.slug == slug).first()
```

where `BlogPost` is a sqlalchemy model.

When I create a new post, everything is fine, it is added and saved in DB, however, nothing happens when I edit an existing post. I've tried `DBSession.flush()`, result is the same - I can create a new post, but existing one is not updated. What am I missing?

Comment: Why are you calling `transaction.commit()` explicitly? By using `transaction.manager` as a context manager, `commit()` is *already* being called when the code block completes.

Comment: Initially I didn't have it, but searching online found that calling `transaction.commit()` explicitly might do the trick, thus I've added.

Comment: The session doesn't appear to track your `process` object; how did you get that object?

Comment: I'm simply calling `classmethod` on BlogPost: `post = BlogPost.by_slug(slug)` and then passing it to the view together with request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, the issue was, that I didn't have `pyramid_tm` under `pyramid.includes` in `ini` configuration:

```
[app:main]
use = egg:myproject

pyramid.includes =
    pyramid_jinja2
    pyramid_tm #this was missing
```

Weird, that I was not seeing any errors or anything, and it sort of worked, but was giving a lot of headaches.

Answer (score 1):

Why your use transaction here?
The `ZopeTransactionExtension` on the `DBSession` in conjunction with the pyramid_tm being active on your project will handle all commits for you.

so just try this:

```
def create_update(request, post):
  title = request.POST.get('title', None)
  content = request.POST.get('content', None)

  post.title = title
  post.content = content

  if post.id is None:
      DBSession.add(post)
```

Comment: Nothing happens this way either. Post is not updated. Plus something weird going on when I try to create a new `Post`. Every third GET request that newly created post (which is not committed to DB) appears in the list of all posts.